# Calculate histogram in resample environment of xarray

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, python-xarray

I have a question regarding a very flexible calculation of histograms.

Assume you have 30 different data sets (lets say model results) and you want to compare the histograms of each data set. The data sets can be 1D (time), or 2D(x,y) or 3D(x,y,t). Below is an example of single 3D data set over 1 month:

```
In [2]: a = xarray.open_dataset("ECMWF_ERA-40_subset.nc")
In [3]: a
Out[3]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 73, longitude: 144, time: 62)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 ... 350.0 352.5 355.0 357.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 90.0 87.5 85.0 82.5 ... -85.0 -87.5 -90.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-07-01T12:00:00 ... 2002-07-31T18:00:00
Data variables:
    tcw        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    tcwv       (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    lsp        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    cp         (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
```

Let's further assume, that my code is dedicated to handle very flexible settings regarding temporal aggregation and spatial aggregation. I.e. I can control the temporal aggregation of the histograms to be computed: monthly, daily, seasonally, monthly over many years, etc. To have this flexibility in temporal aggregation I utilized up to now the `xarray.resample` or `xarray.grouby` method, which can be customized for own functions:

```
In [8]: a.resample({'time': 'W'}).mean(dim="time")
Out[8]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 73, longitude: 144, time: 5)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-07-07 2002-07-14 ... 2002-08-04
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 ... 350.0 352.5 355.0 357.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 90.0 87.5 85.0 82.5 ... -85.0 -87.5 -90.0
Data variables:
    tcw        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 10.668642 ... 0.2204895
    tcwv       (time, latitude, longitude) float32 10.589867 ... 0.21552403
    lsp        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 0.00013404127 ... 6.614067e-05
    cp         (time, latitude, longitude) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I'm wondering how to flexibly visualize the histograms for all datasets and regarding all timestamps (in my case 4 different weeks each of size `x=144`, `y=73`, `t~15`). What would be a fast way?

Why I am asking the question?

1. One possibility is to open the first dataset, cut out the first week, compute the histogram and plot it; open the next data set, cut out the first week, compute the histogram and plot it... This is done up to the last dataset and then all files are close. Afterwards, the second week is analyzed for all datasets. For me this seems to be weird because I don't know how to select the first week without using resample functionality of xarray or pandas. Please note the flexibility: it could be also the first day that is extracted or the first month or each hour of the day (00UTC, 01UTC, 02UTC, groupby method).
2. The second possibilty is to utilize the resample functionality. That means doing in the first step something like this for all datasets:

   ```
   a.resample({'time':'W'}).apply(histogram)
   ```

   but this would mean that I have to store the result of the histogram in a netcdf file. How can this be done and is this really faster? Moreover, in a second step I have still to visualize the result which I foresee problematic, all the histogram plot of python or R is trimmed to get the whole dataset as input and not only the ready histogram data.

Comment: In computing these histograms, do you want to also aggregate over spatial dimensions latitude and longitude?

Comment: At the moment, the idea is to put all data into histogram calculations that can be found in {"lon": [0:-1], "lat":[0:-1],"time":[start(aggregidx:end(aggregidx)]}. Later on, there will be the option to analyze histograms only for a specific region (Europa, Amerika, ..) but then I will use, at first, mask files to multiply the data with and 2) I will compute the histograms.